# Android Sdk manager not found- Flutter doctor error

Tags: android, flutter, sdk, command-prompt

I installed flutter and it was working fine but after updating it to recent version, flutter is not able to find the android sdk manager. I've tried running flutter doctor and tried to install android licenses but the error "Android Sdkmanager not found is shown". I've attached the image of my command prompt [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywu8K.png).

Here's what I've already tried but didn't worked...

1. I had cmd tools installed in my android studio, so I uninstalled and reinstalled it.
2. Changed path settings, added my sdk path to environment variables.
3. Also added cmd tool path to system variables.
4. Deleting the cmd tools and downloading it from android studio official site and pasting it into the sdk manager folder.
5. Changing the sdk path to the sdk manager folder path in command prompt.
6. Running command prompt as administrator.

I've attached the image of command prompt with 'flutter doctor -v' [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uo1wb.png)

I've tried almost everything I found on google but nothing seems to solve my problem. I don't know what should I do next and I'm stuck in it from two days.

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kevIF.png) the flutter doctor --android-licenses -v image

Please help, Thanks.

Comment: Please checkout this link : https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/201/android-sdkmanager-not-found-error-flutter/

Comment: Also tried this way, but didn't work.

Comment: Try reinstalling Android Studio

Comment: I've also reinstalled android studio and flutter, still the error continues.

Comment: Can you provide me with remote access to your system for understanding and debugging your issue

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure to follow [the official documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows#android-setup) step by step to install and set up Android SDK for Windows (Maybe uninstall first everything from before to remove any kind of conflict that exist). Also, don't install the `Command line tools only` and include it to `PATH` (Remove every related Android SDK `PATH` or even other environment variables that are still there too). The recommended way is inside the Android Studio in `Preferences -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK -> SDK Tools` and select `Android SDK Command-line Tools`.

[image]

Second, make sure you restart the command prompt for the changes to take effect. For example, changing `PATH` doesn't update the running processes. So, just restart the ones that need the new configurations. Sometimes even restart the entire system so every process has the updated configurations.

And then try again to accept the licenses:

```bash
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Comment: I did, Please check the image I've provided.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Could you please try that?

Comment: I tried your way but the error remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem stated above, the android sdkmanager.bat file was getting deleted automatically by an antivirus named "SAntivirus". I uninstalled the file from my program files and it worked. Now my flutter doctor is working fine and accepted all the licenses. Thank you all for your support.

Answer (score 0):

you should install the android sdk command line tools in sdk tools on your android studio ( uncheck the hid obselute pacakges ).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).